# Keeping computers on a network up to date

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, windows-update

I have 4 Windows-7 machines at home , and one of them is downloading update all the time invariably , Microsoft is happy with this setup for which they no doubt have a solid reason.

But I don't like my bandwidth hogged by duplicate downloading  of files.

Is there an automated  way to centralize the updates so that at least the common updates are downloaded at a particular location and then users can update their machine from the downloaded repository ?

( I believe WSUS requires Windows Server , which i do not have )

Comment: im not sure wsus does need a server os actually. try it.

Comment: Are they all running the same version of Windows 7?

Comment: yes all the versions are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably run [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) on one system (no need for windows server), pop it in a shared folder, and update the others from that. I suspect you can probably use task scheduler to automate the whole process, and turn off automatic updates on the systems in question.

Comment: will try that and update